# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error in response of Azure AD v2.0 authentication

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph to access a user’s Microsoft account data from within a Node.js web application, to call rest APIs. But once authentication done, instead of return to `ReturnURL`, I'm getting `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in the browser.

Below is the Node application, I'm using:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript

As I see, it seems like some how access token is conflicts and due to that passport is not able to authenticate my requests.

Can someone please help me out here, where I'm missing here. I didn't make any major changes in the app.

Please let me know if someone need more info.

Thanks.

Comment: The code sample you past only demonstrate using the Microsoft Graph SDK. How did you authenticate with Azure AD?

Comment: I created a app using https://apps.dev.microsoft.com, then configure Client Id and Client Secret, redirectURL, IdentityMetaData. I deployed my app at cloud to get https. I've my organization account, so authenticated with my organization account.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a couple of examples of this occurring. It's hard to tell exactly what is happening from the limited information you've provided but here are some examples of what I've seen in the past:

- `redirect_uri` pointing to an endpoint that automatically redirects the user back to  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?`. This results in an infinite loop.
- `redirect_uri` is returning a `HTTP 3xx` status indicating a redirect (`301`, `302`, `303`, `307`, `308`).
- `redirect_uri` is pointing to a page that checks for an authenticated user. Since the user hasn't authenticated yet (you've got an `authorization_code` but not an `access_token` yet) it triggers the authentication workflow again.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the response. I doing nothing but just created app at App Registration Portal, and configure the credentials in nodejs app.

Comment: As you said, below is the url which is responsible for too many redirects. I don't understand when you say "user hasn't authenticated yet, but I'm redirect back to redirect_url once I authenticate, no ?". But I don't see either authorization code or access_token in below url.

"https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?redirect_uri=****&response_type=code&response_mode=query&client_id=****&state=****&nonce=****&scope=User.Read Mail.Send Files.ReadWrite openid&x-client-SKU=passport-azure-ad&x-client-Ver=3.0.8"

Comment: One more thing, I'm using my organization email id to get authenticated or also used same to create app.

Comment: What's the `redirect_uri` or which url was redirected to? You may track the response after you input the credentials and to see whether the app handle the response properly.

Comment: Hi Fei, The redirect_url is https://****/token and it seems authentication is getting failed, and due to which again it is redirected to login.microsoftonline.com/...   url. I also tried same app with PHP platform and getting same response.

Is that something to be done at permission level ? I've USER.Read permission in my application.

If yes, then do I need certain required permission to be granted from admin. I can see there are two types of permission which can be grated either by user or admin.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` is your redirect uri?

Comment: No, It's my web app url suffixed with /token.

Comment: What is your app getting returned to the `token` endpoint and what is your app doing with it? Can you provide a code sample of that process?

Comment: Below is trying to returned with my web app. (https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?redirect_uri=https://<my-app-domain>/token&response_type=code&response_mode=query&client_id=<app-id>&state=<state>&nonce=<nonce>&scope=User.Read Mail.Send Files.ReadWrite openid&x-client-SKU=passport-azure-ad&x-client-Ver=3.0.8)

Below is definition of /token route. Except renderSendMail(req, res) at line 49, I'm rendering my custom template i.e. renderUpload(req, res); 

(https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-connect-rest-sample/blob/master/routes/index.js)

Comment: I'm not making any major changes in the app. I'm using same what was given rest sample.